# Exact html to pdf convert

Tags: php, pdf, rendering

I am writing an application (using Laravel framework), where user manually designs a poster, flyer and some other printable stuff. So i made a JavaScript tool to allow above. In backend i have to make itprintable, so i tried to convert it to pdf. And that's where problems occure i.e.:

1. html design is made in px and as far now i don't know how to recalculate it to mm which pdf operates in,
2. fonts are being renderet different 
   etc.

I tried using https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf , https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy (which uses http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ ) but both give similar outputs.

Does anybody know a solution how to convert content made in browser to printable version?

Comment: Very trick thing to done with backend, you should try to make it Printable from browser. 
Or try to use NodeJS for this as it has cheerio and stuff

Comment: Is there any specific reason that you choose PDF? I'm not sure about your `javascript` + `html` code, but maybe if you try to convert it to an image like `jpeg` it would be more plausible

Comment: I have to make some output for printing house and usually pdf is used for this purpose.

Comment: @anwerjunaid I don't get what would NodeJs change in this case. And about browser printing- have no idea how it could work.

Comment: Take a look at www.cloudformatter.com it uses external server and conversion of HTML to xsl fo

Answer (score 0):

use this formula to convert pix into mm:

```
$witnInMM = floor(($withInPx * 25.4) / $dpi]);
$heightInMM = floor(($heightInPx * 25.4) / $dpi]);
```

Also I am working on a similar project and to convert the images to pdf I am using Imagick. I tried snappy laravel but won't work with CMYK colours.